# Href con evento de click para ejecutar funcion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funciones

queria saber si de alguna forma se podria hacer que al clickear un tengo con href se ejecute una funcion y como seria (teniendo disponible jquery y js). Se me habia ocurrido algo asi pero no funciona, muchas gracias.

```
<a href="funcion(x)">Y</a>
```

Comment: ¿ya intentaste con un simple onClick en vez de href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está mal planteado, la propiedad `href` en las etiquetas `<a>` sirve para determinar el link al que redigiría el enlace, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="https://www.google.es/">Google</a>
```

Si lo que quiere es que al pulsar en el link se ejecute una funcion JS tiene que usar la propiedad `onclick`:

```
<button onclick="Funcion()">Hago algo</button>
```